# SQL Query Find x rows forward the highest value without having a lower value in between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the left 2 columns.
I am trying to achieve the 3th column based on some logic.

Logic: If we take date 1/1 and go further the highest score that wil be reached with going further in dates before the score goes down will be on 3/1. With a score of 12. So as HighestAchievedScore we will retrieve 12 for 1/1. And so forth.

If we are on a date where the next score goes down my highestAchieveScore will be my next score. Like you can see at 3/01/2014

```
date        score   HighestAchieveScore
1/01/2014   10      12
2/01/2014   11      12
3/01/2014   12      10
4/01/2014   10      11
5/01/2014   11      9
6/01/2014   9       8
7/01/2014   8       9
8/01/2014   9       9
```

I hope I explained it clear enough.
Thanks already for every input resolving the problem.

Comment: Result is in the thirth column.

Comment: what version of mssql? (2008, 2012 ?)

Comment: How did you get a highscore of 12 on the first date when the only score up to that time was only 10?

Comment: the thirth column is derived by going forward in the records. If we want to find the HighestAchievedScore starting from 1/1. We move forward till we get a drop in the score. So the highest value we retrieve is 12 on 3/1. This brings our HighestAchievedScore on 12 on 1/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Score TABLE
(
    ScoreDate DATETIME,
    Score INT
)

INSERT INTO @Score
VALUES
('01-01-2014',   10),
('01-02-2014',   11),
('01-03-2014',   12),
('01-04-2014',   10),
('01-05-2014',   11),
('01-06-2014',   9),
('01-07-2014',   8),
('01-08-2014',   9);
```

Now we are going to number our rows and then link to the next row to see if we are still going up

```
WITH ScoreRows AS
(
    SELECT 
    s.ScoreDate,
    s.Score,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ScoreDate) RN
    FROM @Score s
),
ScoreUpDown AS
(
    SELECT p.ScoreDate,
        p.Score,
        p.RN,
        CASE WHEN p.Score < n.Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END GoingUp,
        ISNULL(n.Score, p.Score) NextScore
    FROM ScoreRows p
    LEFT JOIN ScoreRows n
        ON n.RN = p.RN + 1
)
```

We take our data recursively look for the next row that is right before a fall, and take that value as our max for any row that is still going up. otherwise, we use the score for the next falling row.

```
SELECT 
    s.ScoreDate,
    s.Score,
    CASE WHEN s.GoingUp = 1 THEN d.Score ELSE s.NextScore END Test
FROM ScoreUpDown s
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ScoreUpDown d 
    WHERE d.ScoreDate > s.ScoreDate
        AND GoingUp = 0
) d;
```

Output:

```
ScoreDate   Score   Test
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 10  12
2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 11  12
2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 12  10
2014-01-04 00:00:00.000 10  11
2014-01-05 00:00:00.000 11  9
2014-01-06 00:00:00.000 9   8
2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 8   9
2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 9   9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work.... but this is the general concept.

Self join on A.Date < B.Date to get max score, but use coalesce and a 3rd self join on a rowID assigned in a CTE to determine if the score dropped on the next record, and if it did coalesce that score in, otherwise use the max score.

NEED TO TEST but have to setup a fiddle to do so..

```
WITH CTE as
(SELECT Date, Score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Date ASC) AS Row FROM tableName)
SELECT A.Date, A.Score, coalesce(c.score, Max(A.Score)) as HighestArchievedScore
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE B
 on A.Date < B.Date
LEFT JOIN CTE C
 on A.Row+1=B.Row
and A.Score > C.Score
GROUP BY A.DATE, 
         A.SCORE
```

Comment: That will not work, you are looking for max value in all future scores, nothing in this query takes care of drops in score. Score can drop and than go higher than local max.

Comment: Correct this does not solve it. However nice approach.

Comment: I see now I missed the drop in score requirement.

Comment: Your CTE outputs only 2 columns (Date and Row). In your SELECT clause you refer also to score, that isn't anymore in the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting the third column to be computed, you can create the table like this (or add the column to an existing table), using a `function` to determine the value of the third column:

```
Create Function dbo.fnGetMaxScore(@Date Date)
Returns Int
As Begin
    Declare @Ret Int

    Select  @Ret = Max(Score)
    From    YourTable
    Where   Date > @Date

    Return @Ret
End

Create Table YourTable
(
    Date     Date,
    Score    Int,
    HighestAchieveScore As dbo.fnGetMaxScore(Date)
)
```

Comment: Also nice approach working with the function. Functionally the same error as the other answer. (see screenshot other answer)

Answer (score 0):

This should work on SQL Server 2012 but not earlier versions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date,
        LEAD(score) OVER (ORDER BY date) nextScore
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT t.date, score,
    CASE 
        WHEN nextScore < score THEN nextScore
        ELSE (
            SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t1.score), t.score)
            FROM yourTable t1
            JOIN cte ON t1.date = cte.date
            WHERE t1.date > t.date
              AND ISNULL(nextScore, 0) < score
            )
    END AS HighestAchieveScore
FROM yourTable t
JOIN cte ON t.date = cte.date
```